# Onclick checkbox, update the database on particular item - android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I want to update my database on click of my checkbox

[image]

But I have no idea how I can capture the item no. of my item list by clicking the checkbox.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_bucket_item);

int value = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("bucketno");
DatabaseHandler myDbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(this);

BucketItem[] bucketItems = myDbHelper.getAllContacts(value);
BucketItemAdapter adapter = new BucketItemAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, bucketItems);

listView2 = getListView();
View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_header, null); 
listView2.addHeaderView(header);
listView2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

activity_bucket_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

row_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/lightgray"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/completed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bucketNo"
        android:layout_width="29dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bucketItemName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.97" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bucketItemNo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I click the checkbox, then call the update method of my database? any idea?

Note:

I have researched that I can override the

```
onListItemClick(ListView listView, View v, int position,
            long id)
```

method to make this work, but I can't because I plan to use this method when the user click the item list, the description and image will pop-up.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put some Id of row to your checkbox when creating view in adapter by setTag() method. Then extract it when you handle check state change. Something like this:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    int id = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
}
```